# Loop to run regression on multiple dependent variables

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, regression, tidyverse

I have data such as this. I would like to run a linear regression on multiple variables separately without having to copy paste the regression.

```
dat <- read_table2("condition   school  Q2_1    Q2_2    Q2_4    Q2_8    Q2_10   Q2_11   Q2_14   Q2_15
1   A   3   4   3   2   2   4   4   2
0   B   3   3   3   2   1   2   2   1
1   C   4   4   4   3   3   4   3   3
0   D   3   4   3   3   2   2   4   2
1   A   2   4   2   3   3   3   3   3
0   B   2   4   4   2   3   2   2   3
1   C   3   3   3   2   3   3   2   3
0   D   4   4   3   3   3   2   2   3
1   A   3   3   3   3   2   3   3   2
0   B   3   3   3   2   3   3   4   1
1   C   4   4   4   4   3   3   3   3
0   D   3   3   4   3   3   4   4   2
1   A   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3
0   B   3   3   3   2   2   2   2   3
1   C   3   4   3   1   2   3   3   3
0   D   3   4   2   2   3   4   3   3
1   A   4   4   4   3   3   4   3   2
0   B   4   2   3   2   3   2   2   1
1   C   4   3   3   4   3   4   3   3
0   D   3   3   3   2   2   2   3   2
1   A   4   2   3   3   2   2   2   3
")
```

I could run this separately and then pull out the coefficients.

```
 model1 <- lmer(Q2_1~ (1|school) + condition ,data=regression_data , REML = F)
 model2 <- lmer(Q2_2~ (1|school) + condition ,data=regression_data , REML = F)
 model3 <- lmer(Q2_4~ (1|school) + condition ,data=regression_data , REML = F)

summary(model1)$coefficient
summary(model2)$coefficient
summary(model3)$coefficient
```

But I rather do this in one chunk of code. I adjusted some code online to come up with this:

```
# outcome
out_start=3
out_end= 10
out_nvar=out_end-out_start+1

out_variable=rep(NA, out_nvar)
out_beta=rep(NA, out_nvar)
out_se = rep(NA, out_nvar)
out_pvalue=rep(NA, out_nvar)

# exposure
exp_start=1
exp_end=2
exp_nvar=exp_end-exp_start+1

exp_variable=rep(NA, exp_nvar)
exp_beta=rep(NA, exp_nvar)
exp_se = rep(NA, out_nvar)
exp_pvalue=rep(NA, exp_nvar)

number=1

library(lme4)
for (i in out_start:out_end){
  outcome = colnames(dat)[i]
  for (j in exp_start:exp_end){
    exposure = colnames(dat)[j]
    model <- lmer(get(outcome) ~ get(exposure) + (1|school) + condition, 
                  data=dat , REML = F, na.action = na.exclude)
    
    Vcov <- vcov(model, useScale = FALSE)
    beta <- fixef(model)
    se <- sqrt(diag(Vcov))
    zval <- beta / se
    pval <- 2 * pnorm(abs(zval), lower.tail = FALSE)
    
    out_beta[number] = as.numeric(beta[2])
    out_se[number] = as.numeric(se[2])
    out_pvalue[number] = as.numeric(pval[2])
    out_variable[number] = outcome
    number = number + 1
    
    exp_beta[number] = as.numeric(beta[2])
    exp_se[number] = as.numeric(se[2])
    exp_pvalue[number] = as.numeric(pval[2])
    exp_variable[number] = exposure
    number = number + 1
  }
}


outcome = data.frame(out_variable, out_beta, out_se, out_pvalue)
exposure = data.frame(exp_variable, exp_beta, exp_se, exp_pvalue)


library(tidyverse)
outcome = outcome %>% 
  dplyr::rename(
    variable = out_variable,
    beta = out_beta,
    se = out_se,
    pvalue = out_pvalue,
  )

exposure = exposure %>% 
  dplyr::rename(
    variable = exp_variable,
    beta = exp_beta,
    se = exp_se,
    pvalue = exp_pvalue,
  )
all = rbind(outcome, exposure)
all = na.omit(all)
```

This does not give me quite what I want -- it gives me the impact of being in the condition group for each dependent variable (question) but doe not show me the value of the intercept.

For example, for Q2_1 I expect to see:

```
model_lmer <- lmer(Q2_1~(1|school) + condition ,data=dat , REML = F)
summary(model_lmer)$coefficient
             Estimate Std. Error df    t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.1000000  0.2079585 21 14.9068177 1.213221e-12
condition   0.1727273  0.2873360 21  0.6011334 5.541851e-01
```

Instead I see:

```
     var         beta        se           p value 
1   Q2_1     1.727273e-01   0.2873360   0.54775114
3   Q2_1    -2.559690e-15   0.3737413   1.00000000
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `base R` solution. I hope this helps:

```
library(lme4)
#Apply
models <- function(x)
{
  model1 <- lmer(x~ (1|school) + condition ,data=dat , REML = F)
  return(model1)
}


y <- apply(dat[,-c(1,2)],2,models)
#Extract results
extract <- function(x)
{
  z <- as.data.frame(summary(x)$coefficient)
  z$id <- rownames(z)
  z <- z[,c(dim(z)[2],1:(dim(z)[2]-1))]
  rownames(z)<-NULL
  return(z)
}
#Extract summary with function
DF <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(y,extract)))
#Format variables
DF$var <- gsub("\\..*","",rownames(DF))
#Arrange columns
DF <- DF[,c(dim(DF)[2],1:(dim(DF)[2]-1))]
rownames(DF)<-NULL

     var          id     Estimate Std. Error     t value
1   Q2_1 (Intercept)  3.100000000  0.2079585 14.90681768
2   Q2_1   condition  0.172727273  0.2873360  0.60113340
3   Q2_2 (Intercept)  3.300000000  0.2251503 14.65687832
4   Q2_2   condition  0.063636364  0.3110898  0.20455947
5   Q2_4 (Intercept)  3.100000000  0.1928371 16.07574475
6   Q2_4   condition -0.009090909  0.2664427 -0.03411956
7   Q2_8 (Intercept)  2.300000000  0.2212714 10.39447415
8   Q2_8   condition  0.427272727  0.3057304  1.39754743
9  Q2_10 (Intercept)  2.500000000  0.1855144 13.47604443
10 Q2_10   condition  0.045454545  0.2563249  0.17733173
11 Q2_11 (Intercept)  2.500000000  0.2404001 10.39933014
12 Q2_11   condition  0.681818182  0.3321605  2.05267707
13 Q2_14 (Intercept)  2.800000000  0.2313147 12.10472106
14 Q2_14   condition  0.018181818  0.3196072  0.05688801
15 Q2_15 (Intercept)  2.100000000  0.2079585 10.09816681
16 Q2_15   condition  0.627272727  0.2873360  2.18306339
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! My data is very similar, except it has all the a few more columns. However, I get the following error when I ran your code. Error in asMethod(object) : not a positive definite matrix
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Problem with Hessian check (infinite or missing values?)
3: In vcov.merMod(model) :

Comment: @NewBee That error must be due to data quality. At some point there is not convergence and inverse of matrices can not be computed. You should check the algorithm for the model :)

Comment: @NewBee Also be sure about the class of the rest of your variables. You included only numeric variables so adding a factor could mess up everything. As final point colinearity can also produces errors similar to those you mentioned.

Comment: thanks, yes all the variables are numeric (other than school). What's weird is that when I run the model on each variable separately, it runs fine. By checking alorithm do you mean the liner regression model?

Comment: @NewBee yeah `lmer` model. Are `condition` and `school` in position 1 and 2 of your dataframe? Also check for `NA`.